# If statement in the php multidimensional array

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I have a php code like this

```
$output .= '<div>';
$output .= sprintf('<input type="text" name="%s"/>', $field['input_name']);
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```

These input fields can be duplicated. So `$field['input_name'] is a multidimensional array`

So it looks like this

```
name[first_name][1][1]
```

If I duplicate that field it looks like this

```
name[first_name][2][1]
```

I would like to display a button if the name field looks like `name[username][][]`

I've tried like this. But its not working.

```
if ($field['input_name'] == 'name[username][][]') {
    $output .= '<input type="submit" value="Testing">';
}
```

Can someone give me the correct syntax?

Thanks

Comment: You need to implement a `foreach()` loop. Smth. like `name[username][][]` is invalid php-code.

Comment: Yes but how can i implement foreach loop without knowing what value it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a `foreach()` loop or some function, that searches your array. Your best friend in this case is [**RecursiveIteratorIterator**](http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).

```
function searchArrayValueByKey(array $array, $needle) {

    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $needle)
        return $value;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Implementation (example):

```
if (searchArrayValueByKey($name['username'], $field['input_name']) {
    $output .= '<input type="submit" value="Testing">';
}
```

If you handle with with big data arrays, this solution might be slow.

Comment: Following the question and then reading this answer makes me wonder how it answers the question. Not the key of the leaf but the key of the root is what to test against (if I had read the question right).